# Reuse UdpClient vs Disposing it

Tags: c#, sockets, endpoint, hole-punching

I am creating a chat application where users are behind a router (NAT). So the main problem is sending those clients a message. The server has no problem receiving messages.

### This is my protocol (rules):

1. `UdpServer` listens for a udp packet from `client A`
2. `Server` receives packet from `client A` and replies with a packet to open the NAT
3. `Server` now becomes a client (server constantly sends packets to `client A` and the client replies to the server notifying it that it got his message) **I reverse the client and server now that the NAT is open**. This is because `client A` can always send a message to the server through tcp.
4. If `Server` sees that `client A` does not reply back to the packets that its constantly sending it marks `client A` as disconnected and stops sending packets.

### This is the code

```
// class that holds infor about client
class ClientBehindNat
{
     public IPEndPoint EndpointListening;
     public string Id;
}
```

thread that listens for new clients (connections):

```
while(true)
{
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
    // create a new udpServer
    using(var udpServer = new UdpClient())
    {
        // allow reusing port 1234
        udpServer.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        // wait to receive data
        var data = udpServer.Receive(ref ep);

        // analyze data make sure it is reliable....

        // maybe data is a reply from a client 
        if(data.IsReply())
        {
             // mark that client replied
             // ....
             continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // save new client
            ConnectedClients.Add(new ClientBehindNat(){EndpointListening=ep});
        }

        udpServer.Connect(ep);
        udpServer.Send( // data notifying client that we got his message)

    }
}
```

thread that constantly sends udp packets to client in order to keep nat open

```
// send packets every 15 seconds in order to leave nat open
timer.elapsed += (a,b)=> {

    foreach (var c in connectedClients)
    {
        // create a copy of udp server so that client can get our response
        using (var copySocket = new UdpClient())
        {
            // allow reusing port 1234
            copySocket.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            copySocket.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
            // log that we will send this request
            // Requests[someId] = ....

            // send it
            copySocket.Send(someData, someData.Length, c.EndpointListening);

            // first thread should be responsible for receiving this response

            // dispose this client                            
        }          
    }
}
```

### This is the question

**Everything works great** BUT is it bad to create a new Socket (UdpClient) per request? If I receive 100 requests I create 100 new sockets and dispose all that. When I try to reuse a udp client updating its endpoints I get an exception. I often need to send a message to `Client A` or maybe `Client Z` thats why I store its endpoint to know how to reach it. **How can I reuse a udpClient updating its endpoints so that I am able to reach the client I am interested in?**

Comment: Why not change the value of `c` instead of making a new `UdpClient`? Did you get any exception with that method?

Comment: For some reason if I change the value of the endpoint the client does not receives the packet. Maybe I am doing something wrong going to keep trying.

Comment: I suggest moving to `Socket` and especially the `SendTo` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should recommend again about using `Socket`s directly, it gives you a lot of flexibility. Check out the following example that uses one socket for UDP connections for both sending and receiving:

```
    private static readonly List<EndPoint> clients = new List<EndPoint>();
    private static readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    private static Socket socket;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        receiveEventArgs.Completed += OnReceive;
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000));
        Receive();

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            lock (clients)
            {
                foreach (var endPoint in clients)
                    socket.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PING"), endPoint);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Receive()
    {
        receiveEventArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[256], 0, 256);
        receiveEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
        socket.ReceiveFromAsync(receiveEventArgs);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
        {
            // Is reply?
            var isReply = true/false;
            if (isReply)
            {
                // Do domething
            }
            else
                lock (clients)
                {
                    clients.Add(e.RemoteEndPoint);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            lock (clients)
            {
                clients.Remove(e.RemoteEndPoint);
            }
        }
        Receive();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. When I was replying to the client that I got the response I was doing this:

```
udpServer.Connect(ep); // <---------------- this was the problem
udpServer.Send(someData);
```

if I never connect and use the SneTo method that @Sourush stated it enables me to keep listening for packets. Therefore now I have:

```
udpServer.Client.SentTo(data, ep)
```